# Шлем и шелом - в чём разница?

Tags: значение-слов

Шлем и шелом - слова разные, значит и понятия разные?

Answer (score 1):

Большой современный толковый словарь русского языка:
[**шлем**](https://slovar.cc/rus/tolk/129873.html) **I** м.
**1**.
Старинный воинский металлический головной убор, защищавший от ударов холодным оружием.
2.
Головной убор особого покроя, закрывающий голову и шею.
3.
Специальный головной убор, предохраняющий голову от ранений, ушибов, лучей тропического солнца и т. п.
4.
Специальное устройство, изолирующее голову человека от внешней среды и обеспечивающее поступление необходимого для дыхания воздуха, кислорода.

[**шело́м**](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-16223.htm) м. устар.
Старинный воинский металлический головной убор, защищавший от ударов холодным оружием; то же, что шлем в 1 зн.
*Черкес на корни вековые,

На ветви вешает кругом

Свои доспехи боевые,

Щит, бурку, панцирь и **шелом.***
А. С. Пушкин. Кавказский пленник.

Шеломы (IX–XIII век) — такое название поначалу носили древнерусские невысокие цельнокованные сфероконические "шапки" (термина "шлем" ещё не было). Они могли снабжаться [бармицей](https://books.google.ee/books?id=9wJTDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA116&lpg=PA116&dq=%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%81%20%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B9&source=bl&ots=UV5U8UcjZb&sig=ACfU3U21ayS0sfi7iSQ5mHWT69A-e65_sw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-rdWV1YnhAhXCk4sKHQiVDOEQ6AEwCnoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%81%20%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B9&f=false), наушами, назатыльником, полумаской, наносником.
[Шелом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B) — это один из видов средневековых шлемов; использовался на Руси и в Азиатских странах. Отличительной чертой является высокая сфероконическая форма с обратным изгибом конической части, а также отсутствие крепления под подбородком, открытое лицо и уши.

Comment: Если к шелому прицеплялись бармица или науши, то это уже - шлем.

Comment: По мнению некоторых оружиеведов, термин «шелом», помимо обозначения конкретного вида защитного наголовья (в средневековье), также был и общим термином, обозначавшим шлем (в том числе и в Древней Руси). Посмотрите ссылку "про бармицу", там одиннадцатый век, обозначение — _шелом._

Comment: Вы забыли про каску. Это иностранное слово не является те же самым, что шлем и сумело вытеснить наше, русское слово "шелом", которое было как раз на своём месте.

Comment: Простите, но на каску в вопросе даже намека нет.

Comment: Вопрос о разнице, а вы ее не даёте, смешиваете разные понятия, путем слияния разных слов.

Answer (score 0):

Шлем закрывает голову ниже ушей. Шелом закрывает голову только выше ушей. Шелом - русское слово, тождественное иностранному слову "каска". Слово "шелом" вышло из обихода, потому что его значение перестали правильно понимать. Слово "шлем" до сих пор в ходу, потому что его понимание не пропало (хотя словарь Даля настаивает, что шлем это и есть - каска, но каска и шлем - разные вещи).

Comment: Странная (**очень странная!**) ситуация — задаёте вопрос; ТУТ ЖЕ, сразу, сами на него отвечаете; необходимых запятых НИГДЕ не ставите; ссылок или примеров не даёте (Даль, конечно, имя волшебное)... В **чём** смысл?

Comment: А! Вы знаете ответ? Понимаю, что никто ответа не даст и отвечаю сам. Брег/берег, плен/полон, древо/дерево... хлад/холод, средина/середина, млад/молод, влас/волос, глас/голос, град/город т.д. - почему не найти сведений о различении данных пар? (а с запятыми у меня напряг - увидите, смело исправляйте).

Comment: Ну так ищите! В чем проблема. Если вы знаете ответ на вопрос, зачем вы здесь задаете вопрос?